# Count of references to a object referenced by file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, posix

Is it possible to programmatically find out count of processes which have opened object referenced by given file descriptor on linux?

If yes, is there any difference if it is a file, a pipe or whatever?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a standard way to do so. You could undoubtedly find out by grubbing around in `/dev/kmem`; it is possible, though unlikely, that you can find out via the `/proc` file system. The type of file shouldn't make any difference. You might note that only one process can open a given file descriptor.  It can then make its own copies of it (`dup2()` etc), or it can create new processes with a copy of it (`fork()`, etc).  There may be multiple open file descriptions for a single file across multiple processes, as well as multiple processes sharing a single open file description.

Comment: Are you asking how many processes are opening the file? AFAIK file descriptors are unique to the process.

Comment: @ed Yes, I meant count of processes which have opened file, pipe or something else.

Comment: I cannot think of a way to do this under Linux - but I may be wrong. What is the use case?

Comment: `lsof` is able to enumerate all open files across all processes. Lsof does so by inspecting the /proc filesystem. Lsof supports a variety of dialects when inspecting kernel data structures, to support different operating systems like Linux or FreeBsd.

Comment: @ed I want to detect that a pipe is not opened by a "sister" process anymore. That means not a child or parent process but the processes with common parent.

Comment: What are you going to do with the information if you find that another process has the pipe open?  Are you looking at the read end or the write end?  Do you need to look for processes with the same end open (so there are multiple readers on the pipe, or multiple writers), or are you looking to see if there is another process on the other end (at least one reader for your write pipe, or at least one writer for your read pipe)?  If you are looking for the 'other' end, you can find out zero vs one or more by trying to read or write.  If you're looking to distinguish one from many, it's harder.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I want to distinguish if the 'other' end of pipe is opened by 1 or 2 processes.

Comment: Ouch!  That's going to be hard.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curiously, the `fuser` program and its output has been standardized by POSIX.  You could call that using `popen` and parse its output.  Unless the user is privileged, the list will be incomplete, and this approach is inherently prone to races.

On Linux, you could read the contents of the `/proc/*/fd` directories and check for referenced to the same file descriptor.  (Same comment about privileges and races applies.)  If you are interested in references to the same file *description* object (which share not just the same file, but also the same file offset because they were created by `dup`/`dup2` or `fork`), you'll have to filter this further using the `kcmp` system call.